# jquery chain search filter in joomla /php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, joomla

i want to create a **multi-field chain search** module in joomla using jquery like in this [site](http://in.bookmyshow.com/)  left corner. If is there any tutorial please put the link here

Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused... You want people to find you a tutorial for a complex web app creation, rather than either trying to find one yourself or look for it elsewhere? I thought SO was more for small nagging issues, rather than large, multidimensional issues...

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a weird question, to ask somebody to google something for you. If you want to create an auto-populating select box you can find a plugin/tutorial here:

http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

You also mention joomla in your question, as if that is related to the problem you're trying to solve. Do you mean that you want to read information from a joomla component into the select boxes?

You can use any javascript within joomla extensions, so I don't see how that's related to the select boxes.